# How to turn of Google Samsung Nexus Galaxy `3g`/`mobile data usage` warning?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, data-monitoring

After turning `data mobile usage warning` on as described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19979/how-do-i-disable-the-data-usage-warning-and-notification-in-ics)

The exceeded-limit notification stay in my notification list which is very annoying. I cannot remove it - ie. I just need it to notify me then I can remove, later on if I start using and the limit exceeds again, notify me again :)

If you know how to, please share.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the notification which will open `Data usage` settings and move the orange warning bar above data usage level.

[image: Data Usage screen]

Next warning will appear when the warning level is exceeded again.

Comment: Very lovely solved. Thank you. Perfectly to be able to swipe it out of the notification list though

Comment: @NamG.VU, if it answers your question, please mark the solution as accepted. The swiping out wouldn't make sense because the warning bar is still below data usage level and you wanted be notified of that situation by setting the bar at this position. Displaying the warning is important because if data usage reaches limit you may be charged much more for data transfer.

Comment: Not totally agree. Why keep displaying? I don't think that is such important - why don't just re-notify the user again when he use `mobile data` the next time?

Comment: Surely will I tick yours as accepted one - just wanna discuss a little more with you on it.

Comment: @NamG.VU, avarage android user may have tens of apps which sync data in the background, so next mobile data usage may happen just a minute after you dismiss the warning. It would be very anoying to hide the notification every minute. Also the notification is defined as "notify me when my mobile data usage level is more than X megabytes" the user than should choose to disable mobile data, set "remind me when usage reaches Y megabytes" or ignore warning. Of course there could be enhancement that swiping notification moves the warning bar by defined amount, but would complicate the interface.