# Data Usage Warning in ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, mobile-data, notification-bar

I found these related questions on the same issue:

- [How do I disable the data usage warning and notification in ICS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19979/16575)
- [How to turn of Google Samsung Nexus Galaxy `3g`/`mobile data usage` warning?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23540/16575)

But, my problem is the graph doesn't show up the limit lines. How to disable the notification now?

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click for larger variants)</sup>

When I try to set mobile data limit I'm getting the message from the second screenshot and it backs to the first image. It is not enabling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it editing the `netpolicy.xml` file manually. Increased the warning limit to 4GB in 3 places as shown in the image and rebooted. Then the notification went-off:

1. Remount `/system` to make it writable (`mount -o remount,rw /system`)
2. Edit `/system/netpolicy.xml` file as root:
   [image: screenshot]
3. Remount `/system` read-only (`mount -o remount,ro /system`) or reboot the device

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the set mobile data limit to show those lines. As seen in the image below:

[image: Check the box!]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Check my edit on that

Comment: @Fasna have you also tried enabling the statistics (setting that switch to "On")? Just thinking aloud (it shouldn't be related, but who knows).

Comment: @Fasna I've never seen the bars missing. But there's a comparable issue on some LG devices, using the wrong interface for battery stats by default. I worked around that one using an "activity explorer" like the one built-in to "Apex Launcher", or the stand-alone [Activity Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.szalkowski.activitylauncher), exploring the "Settings" app for available "activities". You could try that, maybe there's an "alternative activity" hidden where the bars are enabled. No guarantees, however.